# sign value from combobox with enum to another class

Tags: c#

Im trying to sign a selected value from a combobox that holds enum values.

this is where i fill the combobox

```
    cmbPrio.Items.AddRange(Enum.GetNames(typeof(PriorityType.Prioritytypes)));
    cmbPrio.SelectedIndex = (int) PriorityType.Prioritytypes.Normal;
```

This is where im tryingt to set the value in my class

```
private void ReadInput()
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtTodo.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Write something to do!");
            }
            else
            {
                currTasks.Priority = what code should go here??!
                currTasks.Description = txtTodo.Text;
                currTasks.TaskDate = dateTimePickerToDo.Value;
            }
        }
```

My class with the enum:

```
class PriorityType
{
    public enum Prioritytypes
    {
        Very_Important, 
        Important, 
        Normal, 
        Less_Importan
    }
}
```

My class where my get:set is:

```
 private PriorityType priority;
        public PriorityType Priority
        {
            get
            {
                return this.priority;
            }
            set
            {
                this.priority = value;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I want to set a value in the my Task class from my MainForm...
I have writen in the code where i want help..

Comment: I don't think that is a problem or a question. Maybe you could specify what you expect to happen and what is failing.

Comment: I cant figure out how to set the value so that s my problem, i have tried different things but no luck.. :(

Answer (score 0):

Fill the cmbPrio with enum values directly:

```
cmbPrio.Items.AddRange(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Prioritytypes)).Cast<object>().ToArray());
```

So you can assign it as enum value:

```
currTasks.Priority = (Prioritytypes)cmbPrio.SelectedItem;
```

This will also work if SelectedIndex doesn't correspond to the int value behind your enum type, e.g.

```
public enum Prioritytypes
{
    Very_Important = 1, 
    Important = 2, 
    Normal = 4, 
    Less_Importan = 8
}
```

or if you change the order of entries in your combobox.